# Re-Syncing Diverged SVN and Git Repositories

Tags: git, svn, repository, git-svn

I have two repositories one on googlecode and one on github.  I at one point, not too many commits ago had these repositories merged (via these instructions: http://help.github.com/import-from-subversion/).  I was trying to re-merge these commits but when i try git svn rebase or git svn dcommit i get the error:

```
Unable to determine upstream SVN information from HEAD history
```

I tried following the instructions from this question:  but was unable to get the head to match the svn history.  I can find the last common commit to both so I guess i should just roll back to that commit then try to fast forward but I am not sure how to address this.

Answer (score 0):

> If you ever lose your local copy, just run the import again with the
>   same settings and you’ll get another working directory with all the
>   necessary git-svn settings saved.

You **must not** erase svn-metadata (but you done it)

Comment: i still have my local copy, I am not sure what you mean.  Should I import the svn or the git repo?

Comment: You local copy (and probably github mirror) is unusable and useless for sync, because it doesn't have svn-metadata: "Unable to determine upstream SVN" means exactly this